# DNN redirect Loop - only on admin screens

Tags: dotnetnuke

I do not undrstand this problem.

The other issues mentioning this redirect problem is related to portal aliases and full/med trust levels, etc.

I have a .net 4 Classic pool pointing to the recently upgraded DNN install.

Previous version was 5.xxxx, and now I have upgraded to 7.0.5

All the current cms pages work.
When I go to the admin section, and in there choose page management, or host setting in the host section, then I get this problem.

I know dnn is slowly going down the MVC path, although I still see .apx extention floating around, meaning they have not fully cashed into the seo thing, but they are 80% there I guess.

I do not understand where the problem is.

It is almost like half of the site is still on the tabid=x idea, but some of the admin screens is on the more friendly url concept of "/host/HostSettings//tabid/16/portalid/0/Default.aspx" kind of firendly url / MVC conept.

Is there an entry that I can edit to either have everything in friendly urls, or every thing using the tabid concept and then move forward from there?

Or does the redirect problem have nothing to do with friendly urls?

I am a bit lost here, even after developing in DNN for many years...

Thanks in advance!

As per Chris's advice I went through all the tabs in the table and made sure nothing is set to isSecure=True.

Still get: Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.
IS there a way to turn redirect off in the tables?

I have gone through the entire hostSettings and PosrtalSettings tables and compared it with another working system, but could not find anything obvious...

**EDITED**

Now with a few things turned off and debug mode set to true, I get the following:

```
Server Error in '/cms' Application.
```

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]

Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\cms\3fbf2a3e\66b53196\App_Web_xepmxekk.1.cs    Line: 0

Stack Trace:

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   DotNetNuke.UI.Containers.ActionBase.get_ModuleContext() +7
   DotNetNuke.UI.Containers.ActionBase.get_ActionRoot() +30
   DotNetNuke.UI.Containers.ActionBase.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +35

[ModuleLoadException: An error has occurred.]
   DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(String FriendlyMessage, Control ctrl, Exception exc, Boolean DisplayErrorMessage) +397

[PageLoadException: An error has occurred.]
   DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions.ProcessPageLoadException(Exception exc, String URL) +417
   DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions.ProcessPageLoadException(Exception exc) +96
   DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(String FriendlyMessage, Control ctrl, Exception exc, Boolean DisplayErrorMessage) +548
   DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(Control ctrl, Exception exc, Boolean DisplayErrorMessage) +188
   DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(Control ctrl, Exception exc) +40
   DotNetNuke.UI.Containers.ActionBase.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +71
   DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.SolPartActions.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +13
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +145
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772

[PageLoadException: An error has occurred.]
   DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions.ProcessPageLoadException(Exception exc, String URL) +417
   DotNetNuke.Framework.PageBase.OnError(EventArgs e) +629
   System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) +79
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6695
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +245
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +72
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +58
   ASP.default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\cms\3fbf2a3e\66b53196\App_Web_xepmxekk.1.cs:0
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +341
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get to the site settings page, after upgrading to the latest dnn 7.0.6.

I am not sure why it stopped working after the last upgrade, and the started to work on the next upgrade.

But some pages became non editable..

You edit the content, hit save, and then the old content came back.

That is another annoying issue.

I decided to rebuild the CMS from scratch, and have a clean slate, as I think the old CMS has gone through too many upgrades.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking a lot of questions here. I'll address the one on your subject.

1) If you are seeing redirects on the Admin pages, check the database, often times on old upgrades the "issecure" flag will be set on those admin pages, and that will cause odd redirects. If you have access to the database, just check out the TABS table.

Update 4/16/2013
You might try disabling FriendlyURLs all together and see if that helps you at least get into the admin/host pages. On the DB try updating the UseFriendlyUrl setting in hostsettings, if you don't have an ObjectQualifier in your web.config you could use this SQL

```
update hostsettings
set SettingValue = 'N'

where settingname like 'usefriendlyurls'
```

**UPDATE**
Based on the updated question, I'm thinking that you have one of two problems. Either the Skin is having issues due to using the SolPart menu, or more likely, your MODULE Containers are having problems on the page.

I believe you said you can access the ADMIN page now, but not child pages. I would set the Skin the Admin page (through the page settings) to one of the Gravity Skins (whichever you like). Then, once you've saved those settings, try the Apply Skin to All Child Pages, see if that sets the skin on all the admin child pages correctly. If setting the Skin doesn't work, try the same for the Container on the Admin page.

If that works, then you might have to do the same for the HOST menu. Though you might need to do that one through the DB.

Comment: Were they marked as secure? After removing the issecure flag you'll need to recycle/clear cache

Comment: This will be fun! How will I clear that cache without getting to Site / Host Settings? - I recycled the application pool and site on the server..

Comment: i just know it is going to be something obvious

Comment: Recycling the app on the server should do it. Was the IsSecure column marked as 1s (instead of 0s) for all the admin/host pages?

Comment: Yes, they were, but changing them had no effect!

Comment: Just to be sure, do you have multiple portals? By chance did you only disable issecure for one of the,?

Comment: need to check that out! have one old portal on there that I never use. Will get back to you on that one!

Comment: Had a look, no other portal record or any record in that table has the "IsSecure" field set to true

Comment: Are you using any URL rewriting outside of the standard DNN rewriting? Maybe Ifinity URL Master perhaps?

Comment: If you have server access look at the web.config file and search for IFINITY (notice spelling) see if that shows up. Another option is to try to disable the friendly url handling in DNN. I'll update the original answer with how to do that here in a few minutes.

Comment: Updated the answer with a SQL script that should turn off friendly URLs (might need an app recycle after that)

Comment: did a rdp session on the bus to the server from my Android phone. Changed the SQL as suggested. Will now look at the web config.

Comment: I did a search for IFINITY, and there was nothing in the web.config about it. I recycled the app pool, after the sql change but am still able to find pages via the normal route without using tabid=87 kind of thing, which makes me think Friendly URLS are still being processed somehow. Will check the Admin settings table for something there.... Still cannot get to Admin screen.

Comment: DNN will still process the friendly URLs I believe, it just won't "Create" links that are friendly anymore. If you try to go to one of the Admin pages is the URL of the format /default.aspx?tabid=## where ## is the ID?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28404/discussion-between-chris-hammond-and-shaunoreilly)

Comment: I cannot access page settings or any admin pages other than the one with the icons on it. that page does not get rendered from the database as far as I know. I have no web based Admin / host page functionality, and cannot change anything other than in the web config or database.

Answer (score 2):

Shaun, Where is this issue currently. Last we had talked I asked about the Admin urls and TabIDs. I would recommend you find a page, under Admin, such as Site Settings, and figure out what the TabID for that page is.

Then try to go to http://somedomain.com.blah/default.aspx?tabid=## replacing ## with the number of the TabID for the page in question. Let's start there, and see what happens.

Comment: I am going to re-install DNN. First time in 10 years that it has let me down like this. Normally upgrade go ok for me.

Comment: Sorry Shaun, If you want, I might be able to help you out with desktop sharing via Skype this weekend or something christoc - gmail.com

Comment: I am going to sit down now, and try to remove any old dll references, the solpart menu, etc, to see what the issue is. Going to try and run it in debug mode on my own machine, and see what the issues are from a code point of view. Will get back to you after that. ;-)

I also still think a clean install will good anyway, but will be nice to get the old one working to export the content.

Comment: I can get to the site settings page, after upgrading to the latest dnn 7.0.6, and tweaking a shit load of other stuff like pools moved from integrated to classic, etc! But it looks very weird, as the skin is all screwed up. I need to maybe get friendly urls working again. No matter what the fix is now, I think you will definitely get 100 points bounty for staying with me so long and encouraging me...

Comment: Interesting that 706 got you there. As for the Skin, unfortunately 7.* changed a lot of CSS, so tweaks may be necessary, though there may not be too much, just a couple of things that may appear major to start. You can turn friendly URLs back on via the Web.config format=humanfriendly I think was the setting

Comment: I am trying to use the default skin, but that is not even looking right. I am trying to export all the content into a new install, this seems to be quite a difficult task. I have totally lost my confidence in the current dnn install, which have been upgraded at least 10 times. Would like to get my content into a new install, and rebuild my skin with a more responsive fluid design. There had to be something fixed in 706 that sorted out my problem, as nothing else worked!, and I am not sure which part, as Friendly URLS are working again without the redirect loop.

Comment: Depending on what your content actually is, the import/export functionality can get you good, or bad, results :D Basically, the way import/export work in DotNetNuke, it will export Content that is included in modules that support IPortable, an interface used in Module Development, but not all developers choose to implement this interface when they create modules.

Comment: I just need the html cms content / pages. Where is the export functionality?

Comment: I am starting to think that I should just bring the data across somehow, and create the pages via a data migration effort. Don't think this will be too hard... ;-) I am pretty confident with SQL server to DBA level and have done data migrations before....

Comment: The export functionality is either at the PAGE level (import/export) or at the Portal Level you can create a Portal Template from Host/Sites (or something similar to sites)

Comment: The export portal template thing brings across modules that is only installed on the other portal that is on the same DNN install. When I create a new portal from that portal template in the new DNN install, I am unable to view that new portal, as there is a whole bunch of objects not found. The page level export might by my next option. I might be able to hook into the API and develop a hing that can loop through some of the pages, and export heir content. Or I will just have to go through 100 pages, one by one.